# vim does not redraw the screen properly when scrolling the page up or down line-by-line

Tags: terminal, scrolling, redraw

I am connected to a Windows SSH server from a Linux client, on Windows I end up in a Powershell. For small,quick edits I use the [official vim windows console binary](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/vim80-586w32.zip). It seems to work without additional asset files.

Page-Up/Down works normally, cursors too, but when I scroll "past" the bottom or top of the screen one line at a time with the cursors, all lines but the current one get cleared, and I need to force a redraw with `^L` to see them.

I suspect the fault here to not be with vim, but more with MS_OpenSSH/Powershell. However, I think this can be fixed by vim, by hooking something into the event that gets called when the entire page needs to be refreshed.

Comment: There's no autocommand for "when scrolling". There's one for moving the cursor, but that'll happen horizontally as well. Maybe map ^L to your vertical cursor movement keys? Or does it happen when you move multiple lines as well (say, for example, with { or } )